# Eclipse 2020-06 (v4.16) Dark Theme Problems Solution in CSS

Tags: css, eclipse

we have updated recently to Eclipse 2020-06 (v4.16). The dark theme has many background colors issues like selected file is not clearly visible on not active tabs. Also in code intelligence PopUps selected items are not highlighted. Are there any ways to manually fix these error by changing CSS files under eclipse installation Theme folder in Plugins directory.
We have tried to change CSS elements but it seems there are no options to change or we do not know correct CSS elements. We also tried CSS Spy but its seems to not more managed for new versions.
So any list of CSS options will be helpful. Al last we have to switch to previous version as Bug has been reported to Eclipse.

Screen shots show v4.15 vs v4.16 issues as example for Project Explorer.[image]

Comment: Would be the [Spectrum Dark Theme](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/spectrum-dark-theme) an option for you?

Comment: @howlger This plugin is also not changing colors on Project Explorer,

Comment: Which bug has been reported? About which operating system are you talking?

Comment: @howlger https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=564960

Comment: Those look like Windows file locations.

Comment: See https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=562043#c30